# Select Tag with different methods and actions per options

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

would it be possible to somehow create a select dropdown that automatically sends it to a specific action (I can use onchange => this.form.submit) but the problem is that every option will lead to a different method and action.

For example

Select
  option 1: Delete # This should redirect to a @post method: delete
  option 2: Do Something #this should redirect to do_something_posts method: get

basically each option should be able  to do a different 'redirect to an action'

Thanks!

Comment: you can make use of ajax, then get the value of the select element value. then you can make use of that value to do your process

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do in rails way

```
<%= select_tag("id", options_for_select(list), data: {url: your_path, remote: true, method: :post_or_get}, prompt: "please...") %>
```

This will hit your action with selected value of select tag.

Comment: problem with this is that the url and method will be dependent on whatever  option they select, unless I add a jquery feature though I'm hoping there's some rails way